# Trying Wireguard on Raspberry Pi failed with “RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported”

Tags: raspberry-pi, wireguard

### Steps I tried

1. I am trying to setup a Wireguard client on a Raspberry pi. This is the configuration used

   ```
   # /etc/wireguard/wg0-client.conf
   [Interface]
   Address = 10.10.0.4/32
   Address = fd86:ea04:1111::4/128
   SaveConfig = true
   PrivateKey = CLIENT-PRIVATE-KEY
   DNS = 8.8.8.8

   [Peer]
   PublicKey = SERVER-PUBLIC-KEY
   Endpoint = SERVER-PUBLIC-IP:PORT
   AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
   ```
2. After setup the Wireguard config, I run the `sudo wg-quick up wg0-client`, it fails like this:

   ```
   pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo wg-quick up wg0-client
   [#] ip link add wg0-client type wireguard
   RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
   Unable to access interface: Protocol not supported
   [#] ip link delete dev wg0-client
   Cannot find device "wg0-client"
   ```

The Wireguard server side has been working for a while with other devices, so I do not paste the info here.

### OS and hardware context

- `/etc/os-release` info

  ```
  pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
  PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
  NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
  VERSION_ID="10"
  VERSION="10 (buster)"
  VERSION_CODENAME=buster
  ID=raspbian
  ID_LIKE=debian
  HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
  SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
  BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
  ```
- `/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model` for hardware info:

  ```
  Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Did you plug something reciently and use `rpi-update`? I'm having the same issue, and even can't connect or associate with a wireless connection.

Is your raspi conection wired or wireless?

EDIT1:
I think i found the solution. I run these commands and work like a charm.

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-net-mods --reinstall
```

I don't know if it was one another or both.

Hope it helps.
Regards.-

Comment: I just ran the first of those two commands and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your Raspberry is using an old version of Berryboot, the above perhaps will not solve your problem. Berryboot uses a custom kernel which cannot be updated via `upgrade` or the workaround of `install raspberrypi-kernel-headers`.

Instead, one would have to install a newer version of Berryboot which has a [more current kernel](https://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot/changelog).

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/wireguard/wg0-client.conf`, setting

```
[Interface]
MTU = 1412
```

worked for me.